# Is std::decay redundant in std::is_convertible?

Tags: c++, c++17, enable-if, perfect-forwarding

I wrote such code:

```
template <class T>
class A {
  template <class U, class = 
class std::enable_if_t<std::is_convertible_v<std::decay_t<U>, std::decay_t<T>>>>
      void f(U&& val) {}
    };
```

I want that user of my class can call `f` only with types that convertible to `T`.

Is `std::decay` redundant there? If I remove it maybe I miss some special cases?

Comment: That depends; what exactly are you trying to ask? That is, what code are you trying to prevent people from passing?

Comment: @NicolBolas, I am edited post.

Comment: "*I want that user of my class can call f only with types that convertible to T.*" I could guess that from your code. I want to know *exactly* what you mean by that. Do you mean that you want `f` to be able to do `T t = val;` or some equivalent? Do you want users to be able to pass array or function types as `T`?

Comment: @NicolBolas, can you explain what you mean in the last sentence?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your question is more philosophical, as in: In the universe of types in C++, are there any cases of T and U where there is an observable difference between calling f() and g() on the following class:

```
template <class T>
struct A {
 
    template <
        class U, 
        enable_if_t<is_convertible_v<decay_t<U>, decay_t<T>>>* = nullptr
    >
    void f(U&& val) {}

    template <
        class U, 
        enable_if_t<is_convertible_v<U, T>>* = nullptr
    >
    void g(U&& val) {}
};
```

**What does decay_t actually do?**

- remove top-level const/volatile qualifiers
- remove top-level reference qualifiers
- array -> pointer conversion
- function -> function pointer conversion

It may be worth noting: decay_t is modeled on what happens to function argument types when passed into a function.

(UPDATED)

If `U` is taken by value, then `decay_t<U>` will be equivalent to U.

But since `U` is a universal reference (in your example), it is possible that U deduces to reference type, so decaying it will have a visible effect.  When `T` can *only* be constructed from a reference, then decaying it will change the answer of this type trait.

Merry's excellent example:

```
#include <type_traits>
#include <utility>

template <class T>
struct A {
 
    template <
        class U, 
        std::enable_if_t<std::is_convertible_v<std::decay_t<U>, T>>* = nullptr
    >
    void f(U&& val) {}

    template <
        class U, 
        std::enable_if_t<std::is_convertible_v<U, T>>* = nullptr
    >
    void g(U&& val) {}
};

struct B
{
    B(int &) {}
};

void foo() {}

int main() {

    A<B> a1;
    int x = 3;
    // a1.f(x);  // fails to compile: int not convertible to B
    a1.g(x);     // ok; int& is convertible to B
}
```

Comment: Your claim that "std::decay_t<U> should always be equivalent to U" is incorrect:
```
template <class T>
struct A {
 
    template <
        class U, 
        std::enable_if_t<std::is_convertible_v<std::decay_t<U>, T>>* = nullptr
    >
    void f(U&& val) {}

    template <
        class U, 
        std::enable_if_t<std::is_convertible_v<U, T>>* = nullptr
    >
    void g(U&& val) {}
};

struct B { B(int &) {} };

void foo() {}

int main() {

    A<B> a;
    int x = 3;
    a.f(x);
    a.g(x);
}
```
U is int&, decay_t<U> is int, and only g compiles.

Comment: It seems SO doesn't respect triple-backticks in comments. You can see the example code nicely formatted at https://godbolt.org/z/vTx1419Gs. The catch is that since U&& is a forwarding reference, the argument type used in template type deduction is `int&` rather than just `int`, and decay on `int&` is not a no-op.

Comment: @BruceMerry Thank you for the excellent feedback.  I've updated the answer to include your example.